# frequency of items within list of lists

Tags: python

I have a list of lists called bi_grams and I want the frequency of each bigram. The length of bi_grams is 23087 so I might need a loop (?)

```
bi_grams= [[('ABC', 'Memorial'), ('Memorial', 'Hospital')], [('ABC', 'Memorial'), ('Memorial', 'Clinic')]]
```

Expected output

```
dict_items([(('ABC', 'Memorial'), 2), 
(('Memorial', 'Hospital'), 1), (('Memorial', 'Clinic'),1])
```

Ive tried `Counter(map(tuple, bi_grams[0])).items()`
but it only gives me the bigram frequency of the first list.

I've also tried `Counter(map(tuple, bi_grams[0:2])).items()` but it is only giving me the count of each list, not the bigrams within the list.

Would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 3):

You have a nested list which you can flatten with [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable).

Apart from that complication the problem boils down to a simple application of [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) because a `Counter` has no problem with counting tuples.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> 
>>> bi_grams= [[('ABC', 'Memorial'), ('Memorial', 'Hospital')], [('ABC', 'Memorial'), ('Memorial', 'Clinic')]]
>>> Counter(chain.from_iterable(bi_grams))
>>> 
Counter({('ABC', 'Memorial'): 2,
         ('Memorial', 'Clinic'): 1,
         ('Memorial', 'Hospital'): 1})
```

There's also a pretty straight forward solution with a `for` loop:

```
>>> c = Counter()
>>> for x in bi_grams:
...:    c.update(x)
...:    
>>> c
>>> 
Counter({('ABC', 'Memorial'): 2,
         ('Memorial', 'Clinic'): 1,
         ('Memorial', 'Hospital'): 1})
```

Answer (score 2):

`chain.from_iterable` as suggested by @timgeb is probably the way to go, but you could also flatten your list via a list comprehension, and then apply `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

bi_grams= [[('ABC', 'Memorial'), ('Memorial', 'Hospital')], [('ABC', 'Memorial'), ('Memorial', 'Clinic')]]

>>> Counter(i for x in bi_grams for i in x)
Counter({('ABC', 'Memorial'): 2, ('Memorial', 'Hospital'): 1, ('Memorial', 'Clinic'): 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `chain(*iterable)` idiom too:

```
>>> from itertools import chain                                                    >>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(chain(*bi_grams))
Counter({('ABC', 'Memorial'): 2, ('Memorial', 'Hospital'): 1, ('Memorial', 'Clinic'): 1})
```

---

Using `chain(*iterable)`, flattens the list of list of tuples to the inner list, e.g.

```
>>> x = [[(1,2), (3,4)], [(5,6)], [(7,8)]]

>>> list(chain(*x))
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)]
```

`Counter` simply counts what's in the flatten list:

```
>>> x = [[(1,2), (3,4)], [(5,6)], [(7,8)]]

>>> Counter(chain(*x))
Counter({(1, 2): 1, (3, 4): 1, (5, 6): 1, (7, 8): 1})
```