# Frequency on list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

My data are similar in nature to the SO post here:

[frequency of items within list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53015104/frequency-of-items-within-list-of-lists)

But, instead I have:

`mylist = [['hello', 'there'], ['hi', 'there'], ['hello', 'there']]`

I'm trying to count the number of repeating phrases, so, in this case I observe ['hello', 'there'] twice and the other once.

I run into the familiar `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` error, but with data structured as formatted in my example, I haven't been able to find a relevant solution.

The above could be phrases consisting of `n` total words within each separate list and not always `n=2`.

Struggling to get the frequency count in this case, so any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: what is the output that you wish to have?

Comment: A dictionary like `{['hello', 'there']: 2, ['hi', 'there']: 1}` would be good

Comment: Try: `print(Counter(map(tuple, mylist)))` to get your desired result, but with dictionary of tuples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lists aren't hashable, but tuples are:

```py
>>> import collections
>>> counts = collections.Counter([tuple(sublist) for sublist in mylist])
>>> counts
Counter({('hello', 'there'): 2, ('hi', 'there'): 1})
```

This is just a wrapper for a `dict`, and can be accessed as such:

```py
>>> counts[("hello", "there")]
2
```

Comment: Thanks, @tgsmith61591. Unfortunately I do not have tuples in this case, or your suggestion would indeed work.

Comment: So cast them as tuples. You can't use lists as keys in a dictionary

Comment: You are exactly right, this did indeed solve the issue.

Comment: Even simpler: `collections.Counter(tuple(sublist) for sublist in mylist)`.

Answer (score 0):

With no imports and incorporating a little dictionary comprehension can achieve your results.

```
{k:i for i, k in [[i, mylist.count(i)] for i in mylist]}
```

Output:

```
{2: ['hello', 'there'], 1: ['hi', 'there']}
```

---

A little unconventional approach and you can reverse key and value.

```
{f'{", ".join(i)}':v for i, v in [[i, mylist.count(i)] for i in mylist]}
```

Output:

```
{'hello, there': 2, 'hi, there': 1}
```

---

One loop.

```
dict([(tuple(i), mylist.count(i))for i in mylist])
```

Output:

```
{('hello', 'there'): 2, ('hi', 'there'): 1}
```